# Clarify that a tag synonym does not affect questions already tagged?

Tags: feature-request, tags, privileges, tag-synonyms

A recent tag synonym suggestion issue we were having on Movies.SE resulted in finding out that the help Center page for the tag synonym privilege is not clear.

I previously thought that the five person vote (1 to suggest, 4 minimum upvotes) for a tag synonym would automatically and silently retag old questions already bearing the synonym. I was told this was not the case. That they will need manual Merging by the mods.

Reading the help page, ***in hindsight***, seems to say that only when a new question is tagged with the synonym that it will be changed. ***It does not explicitly mention the old tags stay the same.***

**My suggestion is to update the help center/privilege page and the tag synonym suggestion page to explicitly state that old questions won't get retagged, that a meta question requesting merging should be asked instead. Just to clarify.**

I'm sure this results in a few pointless tag synonym requests, as some people think it counts for all questions, not just new ones.